# Calling controller/action is not working as expected?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Click link as controller/function **(signout/signout)** is not working .. I mean if I click link controller/action it's not going to that called function.But controller/action/action **(signout/signout/signout)** is working in my CI framework..

```
//not working
echo "<div id='menu'><ul><li><a href=".site_url("signout/signout").">Signout</a></li></ul></div>";
//working
echo "<div id='menu'><ul><li><a href=".site_url("signout/signout/signout").">Signout</a></li></ul></div>";
```

MY CONTROLLER **Signout.php**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Signout extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        // Call the CI_Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default', true);
    }

    public function index() {

    }

    public function signout() {
        $this->load->view("signout_signout");
    }

}
```

Here I want `controller/action`(signout/signout) to work ! Because 2 worked method url(signout/signout/signout) is a little long ,so don't like it . How can i manage that?

Comment: try to change your function name `signout()`

Answer (score 1):

Call signout() from your index() action. Change:

```
public function index() {

}
```

to

```
public function index() {
    $this->signout();
}
```

or use this and eliminate signout() altogether:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->view("signout_signout");
}
```

Comment: I knew index action is working !  I want to call directly to signout action ! Can I do that without using index action Sir ?

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine as i check your code.

Try test this code and see

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function welcome()
  {
      echo "<div id='menu'><ul><li><a href=".site_url("welcome/signout").">Signout</a></li></ul></div>";
      echo "<div id='menu'><ul><li><a href=".site_url("welcome/signout/sidgnout").">Signout</a></li></ul></div>";
  }

  public function signout()
  {
      echo "signout";
  }

  public function index()
  {

  }

}
```